# How to assign a name for a pytorch layer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

Following [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137298/how-to-detect-source-of-under-fitting-and-vanishing-gradients-in-pytorch), I want to plot weights, biases, activations and gradients to achieve a similar result to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315202/understanding-tensorboard-weight-histograms).

Using

```
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    summary_writer.add_histogram(f'{name}.grad', param.grad, step_index)
```

as was suggested in [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137298/how-to-detect-source-of-under-fitting-and-vanishing-gradients-in-pytorch) gives sub-optimal results, since layer names come out similar to `'_decoder._decoder.4.weight'`, which is hard to follow, especially since the architecture is changing due to research. `4` in this run won't be the same in the next, and is really meaningless.

Thus, I wanted to give my own string names to each layer.

---

I found [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-give-pytorch-layer-a-name/5521) Pytorch forum discussion, but no single best practice was agreed upon.

What is the recommended way to assign names to Pytorch layers?

Namely, layers defined in various ways:

1. Sequential:

```
self._seq = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(1, 2), nn.Linear(3, 4),)
```

2. Dynamic:

```
self._dynamic = nn.ModuleList()
    for _ in range(self._n_features): 
        self._last_layer.append(nn.Conv1d(in_channels=5, out_channels=6, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1,),)
```

3. Direct:

```
self._direct = nn.Linear(7, 8)
```

4. Other ways I didn't think about

---

I would like to be able to give a string name to each layer, defined in each of the above ways.

Comment: For `nn.Sequential` you can provide an _OrderedDict_ of `nn.Modules` thus naming them

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Sequential

Pass an instance of [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Code below gives `conv1.weights`, `conv1.bias`, `conv2.weight`, `conv2.bias` (notice lack of `torch.nn.ReLU()`, see end of this answer).

```
import collections

import torch

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    collections.OrderedDict(
        [
            ("conv1", torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)),
            ("relu1", torch.nn.ReLU()),
            ("conv2", torch.nn.Conv2d(20, 64, 5)),
            ("relu2", torch.nn.ReLU()),
        ]
    )
)

for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(name)
```

### Dynamic

Use [`ModuleDict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleDict.html) instead of `ModuleList`:

```
class MyModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.whatever = torch.nn.ModuleDict(
            {f"my_name{i}": torch.nn.Conv2d(10, 10, 3) for i in range(5)}
        )
```

Will give us `whatever.my_name{i}.weight` (or `bias`) for each created module dynamically.

### Direct

Just name it however you want and that's how it will be named

```
self.my_name_or_whatever = nn.Linear(7, 8)
```

### You didn't think about

- If you want to plot weights, biases and their gradients you can go along this route
- **You can't plot activations** this way (or output from activations). Use [PyTorch hooks](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/nnft_tutorial.html#forward-and-backward-function-hooks) instead (if you want per-layer gradients as they pass through network use this also)

For last task you can use third party library [torchfunc](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/torchfunc) (disclaimer: I'm the author) or go directly and write your own hooks.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I wanted. Can you please explain how `torchfunc` relates to this? What will I be able to di with torchfunc? For example, How would I plot activations and gradients with it?

Comment: @Gulzar it automatically registers recorders (via hooks) which get data coming out of specified layers (which you can later plot), see [documentation](https://szymonmaszke.github.io/torchfunc/packages/torchfunc.hooks/torchfunc.hooks.recorders.html). Also [`flashtorch`](https://github.com/MisaOgura/flashtorch) might help, though I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: Ok now trying to implement this, I see your point about activations. Can you explain please why I can't plot activations like this? Also please note I am using Pytorch Lightning, maybe the hook is already implemented. Which one do I need? `on_after_backward` maybe?

Comment: Also, I see keeping these statistics slows training X100. What is the best practice of trading off logging with speed in this case?

Comment: @Gulzar please avoid multiquestion, post a new one about activations and make it more concrete, thanks.